# Symfony DebugHandlerPass class is deprecated

Tags: php, symfony, travis-ci

have version

```
    "php": ">=5.6",
    "symfony/symfony": "v2.8.13",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "3.0",
```

When run test have this

> The Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler\DebugHandlerPass class is deprecated since version 2.12 and will be removed in 3.0. Use AddDebugLogProcessorPass in FrameworkBundle instead: 1x
>       1x in AppNewsTest::__construct from FooBundle\Tests\Integration\Application\Notifications

all tests done but have this error and in travis have build pass
how ti fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check which monolog-bundle is really resolved:

I am pretty sure it's 2.12 and the 'error' message is simpy telling you that with the current monolog version you're using you're calling a deprecated class.
So only when your monolog bundle really resolves to something like >= 3.0 you will get real trouble.

This is message is only there to prepare you once you upgrade to Monolog 3.0

By the way, the latest Monolog stable version is 2.11.1 according to their releases page - why are you requesting a higher one now? (and how does it fit to you a Symfony < 3)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and updating monolog-bundle to version 3.0.1 fixed it

Comment: I change to monolog-bundle 2.11.1 and fix this